# Error during startup of Spring Boot JPA app with error that entity class is not a manged type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

First I am quite new to Springboot, learning from examples, but I am struggling with a real simple one.

I have a very minimal Springboot App with 1 Main Class, 1 repository, 1 entity.
The database is PosgreSQL.

When starting the application the output contains the error message

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityRepository' defined in com.d043114.minimalJPA.CityRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: **Not a managed type: class com.d043114.minimalJPA.City***

The repository looks like this

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {

}
```

The entity is like this:

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private long ID;
    
    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

}
```

The main class is basic as well

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.d043114.minimalJPA")
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.d043114.minimlaJPA")
public class MinimalJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MinimalJpaApplication.class, args);

        City berlin = new City();
        berlin.setName("Berlin");
        berlin.setIsCapital(true);
        
        City duesseldorf = new City();
        duesseldorf.setName("Düsseldorf");
        duesseldorf.setIsCapital(false);
        
        
        CityRepository cityRepository =   appcontext.getBean(CityRepository.class);

        cityRepository.save(berlin);
        cityRepository.save(duesseldorf);

    }

}
```

I played around with the @EntityScan and @ComponentScan, but am suprised that it is not working, even though repository, main class and entity are under the same package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this annotation as well, over '*MinimalJpaApplication*' class:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.package.base.*")
```

Comment: Hi JustQuest, thank you very much for your response. With this it works.

Comment: Maybe it is okay to raise a follow up question right here with a comment.  When I now try to access the repository in the main class a "No qualifying bean of type .... " is raised. Strange

Comment: Hi, if it fixed your original question, you can accept an answer so it can help other people straggling with the same problem.

For other question, you can open another question if you want. I cannot help you much without error message, "No qualifying bean of type .... " doesn't help me much but from that seems like you didn't put annotation @Autowired over your service.

Comment: I have raised a new question containing the code here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74644076/retrieving-repository-bean-via-context-returns-no-qualifying-bean-available)