# Retrieving Repository Bean via Context returns "No qualifying Bean available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a very simple Springboot JPA Project consisting of a main class a repository and one entity.
First I have had a problem the Springboot throws an error during startup, but this is solved.
Now  I face the problem that I cannot retrieve the Repository Bean in my main class.

It throws
*"No qualifying bean of type 'com.d043114.minimalJPA.CityRepository' available"*

The repository looks like this

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {

}
```

The entity is like this:

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private long ID;
    
    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

}
```

The main class is basic as well

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.d043114.minimalJPA.CityRepository;

@EnableJpaRepositories("com.d043114.minimalJPA.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.d043114.minimalJPA.*")
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.d043114.minimlaJPA")
public class MinimalJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext appcontext = SpringApplication.run(MinimalJpaApplication.class, args);
        
        
        CityRepository cityRepository =   appcontext.getBean(CityRepository.class );

    }

}
```

Comment: Where/how is `appcontext` initialized?

Comment: Are all your beans in the same package?

Comment: There was a cut&Paste Error. appcontext get initlized from the SpringApplication run.
Everything is under one package.

Comment: @Habi , please remove @EnableJpaRepositories("com.d043114.minimalJPA.*") , @EntityScan("com.d043114.minimlaJPA") , @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.d043114.minimalJPA.*") .  It will work . I tried same at my end and its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.d043114.minimalJPA.*")
```

I replaced this with

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.d043114.minimalJPA")
```

and removed this line

```
@EntityScan("com.d043114.minimlaJPA")
```

It is working .

Also if remove all together these lines then also it is working .

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.d043114.minimalJPA.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.d043114.minimalJPA.*")
```

So final code is
CityRepository.java

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long>
{

}
```

City.java

```
package com.d043114.minimalJPA;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long ID;

    public long getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long iD)
    {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

}
```

Main class MinimalJpaApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MinimalJpaApplication
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext appcontext = SpringApplication.run(MinimalJpaApplication.class, args);
        CityRepository cityRepository =  appcontext.getBean(CityRepository.class );


        if ( cityRepository != null )
        {
            System.out.println("We are goood ");
        }
    }

}
```

If you expand @SpringBootApplication , you will see its already taking care of all these things .

Regarding @EntityScan and @ComponentScan , please see below link
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-entityscan-vs-componentscan

"We should be aware that using @EntityScan will disable Spring Boot auto-configuration scanning for entities."

Adding pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.d043114</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimalJPA </artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>minimalJPA </name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  
When deleting @EnableJpaRepositories("com.d043114.minimalJPA.*") 
I do have the problem that the app throws an error during spring boot startup, stating that City is not a manged type.

Comment: @Habi , Keep only "@SpringBootApplication" remove everything else . I am assuming everything is under com.d043114.minimalJPA

Comment: yes, everything is in the same package, but without the EnableJPArRepositories annotation, I have this startup error, as questioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74640754/error-during-startup-of-spring-boot-jpa-app-with-error-that-entity-class-is-not

Comment: @Habi , will you please try with code which I pasted above . I have given every class

Comment: @KnoledgeSeeker, thank you very much. Especially when replacing the POM  it works. The differene is that I would like to use a PostgreSQL DB.

Comment: @Habi , its working with PostgreSQL DB as well . As I said earlier just keep this 
"@SpringBootApplication
public class MinimalJpaApplication " . Also please post your all code after these changes suggested by me